# error: ‘options’ does not name a type

Tags: ros2, c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using ROS 2 Galactic on Ubuntu 20.04. I am trying to create a callback group using the tutorial on ROS2 documentation. I am getting this error

```
error: ‘options’ does not name a type
```

This is how I am defining my group:

```
rclcpp::CallbackGroup::SharedPtr my_callback_group = create_callback_group(rclcpp::CallbackGroupType::Reentrant);
rclcpp::SubscriptionOptions options;
options.callback_group = my_callback_group;
```

I have also tried:

```
auto my_callback_group = create_callback_group(rclcpp::CallbackGroupType::Reentrant);
rclcpp::SubscriptionOptions options;
options.callback_group = my_callback_group;
```

I still get the same error. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404017/error:-%E2%80%98options%E2%80%99-does-not-name-a-type/) by [cjoshi17](https://answers.ros.org/users/75894/cjoshi17/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2022-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found out my problem, I was trying to define this options.callback_group = my_callback_group; after my variable declaration in my class declaration. When I added this in my constructor it worked for me. Thanks for you help

---

Originally posted by [cjoshi17](https://answers.ros.org/users/75894/cjoshi17/) with karma: 28 on 2022-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1